Error: Could not find page for path "/_not-found"
I'm trying to build my Next.js project, that is using i18next and getting following error:

Error: Could not find page for path "/_not-found"

yarn run v1.22.19
$ next build
  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (0/4)  [=   ]Error: Could not find page for path "/_not-found"
    at v (/usr/src/app/apps/desk/.next/server/chunks/614.js:1:1346)
    at Q (/usr/src/app/apps/desk/.next/server/chunks/614.js:12:2151)
    at nj (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46251)
    ... {
  digest: '1530829009'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error: Could not find page for path "/_not-found"
    at v (/usr/src/app/apps/desk/.next/server/chunks/614.js:1:1346)
    at Q (/usr/src/app/apps/desk/.next/server/chunks/614.js:12:2151)
    at nj (/usr/src/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46251)
    ...
 ✓ Generating static pages (4/4)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /_not-found/page: /_not-found
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

When I delete app/[locale] folder, building is successful.
